# Angular-leaflet-directive: Open popup on drop

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm trying to open popup on drop, but it does not work, I've tried with

```
$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMarker.dragend', function(event,args){
   args.model.focus = true;
});
```

and

```
$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMarker.dragend', function(event,args){
    $scope.markers.forEach(function(marker){
        marker.focus = false;
    });
    args.model.focus = true;
});
```

But popup does not open until I drag and drop the marker for second time.
[image: Here how this should work]

That's not how it should work, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `L.Marker`'s `openPopup` method:

> Opens the popup previously bound by the bindPopup method.

http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-openpopup

```
$scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMarker.dragend', function(event,args){
    // Marker which fires the event is stored in args.leafletObject
    args.leafletObject.openPopup();
});
```